# How can I achieve redirect/rewrites in Netlify?

Tags: function, redirect, url-rewriting, cloudflare, netlify

**Context**:

I'm migrating monorepo's frontend apps from Cloudflare from Netlify.
I deployed workers for redirects in Cloudflare like this:

```
# backend/redirect contains src/index.js, package.json, wrangler.toml

# src/index.js
export default {
    async fetch(request) {
        const url = new URL(request.url);

        let split = url.hostname.split(".");

        if (split[0] === "www") {
            split = split.slice(1);
        }

        let subdomain;

        if (split.length >= 3) {
            subdomain = split[0];
        }

        switch (subdomain) {
            case "brands":
                url.hostname = "brand-661.pages.dev";
                break;

            case "docs":
                url.hostname = "docs-cmx.pages.dev";
                break;

            default:
                const search = new URLSearchParams(request.url.search);

                if (subdomain) {
                    search.set("brand", subdomain);
                }

                url.hostname = "consumer-1ja.pages.dev";
                url.search = "?" + search.toString();
        }

        return await fetch(new Request(url, request), {
            cf: {
                cacheTtl: 60,
            },
        });
    },
};
```

I added CNAME DNS record (example.com / redirect.example.workers.dev, *.example.com / redirect.example.workers.dev) redirect the workers name.

**Question**:

How can I achieve the above in Netlify?

**What I tried**:

- I added an app under backend (backend/redirect-netlify) and placed only netlify.toml and package.json.

```
# netlify.toml

[[redirects]]
from = "https://brands.example.com/*"
to = "https://brand-661.pages.dev/:splat"
status = 200


[[redirects]]
from = "https://docs.example.com/*"
to = "https://docs-cmx.pages.dev/:splat"
status = 200

# Default rule for any other subdomain
[[redirects]]
from = "https://:subdomain.example.com/*"
to = "https://consumer-1ja.pages.dev/:splat"
status = 200
```

Netlify says the last redirect ruls is an invalid syntax.

- I tried with Netlify functions. Placed functions/index.js, public/_redirects.

```
# functions/index.js
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    const url = new URL(event.rawUrl);

    let split = url.hostname.split(".");

    if (split[0] === "www") {
        split = split.slice(1);
    }

    let subdomain;

    if (split.length >= 3) {
        subdomain = split[0];
    }

    switch (subdomain) {
        case "brands":
            url.hostname = "brand.netlify.app";
            break;

        case "docs":
            url.hostname = "docs.netlify.app";
            break;

        default:
            const search = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
            if (subdomain) {
                search.set("brand", subdomain);
            }

            url.hostname = "consumer.netlify.app";
            url.search = "?" + search.toString();
    }

    return await fetch(new Request(url), {
        cf: {
            cacheTtl: 60,
        },
    });

    // const response = await fetch(url);
    // const body = response.body();

    // return {
    //  statusCode: 200,
    //  body: body
    // };
};

# public/_redirects
/* /.netlify/functions/index 200
```

This doesn't work neither.

**Side Question**:
Although I added domain example.com to Neltify and DNS record (*.example.com / redirect.netlify.app), https://docs.example.com shows certification error.

Hope your great support.

Thanks.